# Kernel-power error, automatic reset the computer

Tags: windows, bsod, kernel

I have a problem sometimes when i run full screen application, sometimes the machines goes automatically to reboot with no warning, I was looking in the event viewer and seems to be a kernel-power failure.

### Event detaills:

```
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-09-06T10:34:27.615210700Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>108165</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Rami-PC</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I was looking in the event viewer and it seems to be a kernel-power failure.

> The kernel power event ID 41 error occurs when the computer is shut
>   down, or it restarts unexpectedly. When a computer that is running
>   Windows starts, a check is performed to determine whether the computer
>   was shut down cleanly. If the computer was not shut down cleanly, a
>   Kernel Power Event 41 message is generated.
>
> ...
>
> **An underpowered or failing power supply may cause this behavior**
>
> ...
>
> **Scenario 3: The system randomly restarts and no Stop error BugcheckCode is listed, or the computer is completely unresponsive
>   (hard hang)**

This matches your data `<Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data>`

> This scenario usually indicates a problem with the hardware. To help
>   isolate the problem, check the following items:
>
> - Overclocking: Disable overclocking to see whether the issue occurs when the system is run at the correct speed.
> - Check the memory: Verify the memory by using a memory checker. Verify that each memory chip is the same speed and that it is
>     configured correctly in the system.
> - Power supply: Make sure that the power supply has enough wattage to appropriately handle the installed devices. If you added
>     memory, installed a newer processor, installed additional drives, or
>     added external devices, such devices can require more energy than the
>     current power supply can provide consistently.
> - Overheating: Check whether the system is overheating by examining the internal temperature of the hardware.
> - Defaults: Reset the system back to the system defaults to see whether the issues occur when the system is running in its default
>     configuration.

Source [Windows Kernel event ID 41 error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504)